# Clone working but can't clone it through ajax using jquery

Tags: jquery

jquery cloning is working, for example,

```
$("#treeFile" > ul:first > li:first ul > *).clone().appendTo("#dummyTree");
```

However when attempting to send this clone to a post ajax, the file is empty...

```
var cloneTree = $("#treeFile" > ul:first > li:first ul > *").clone();


$.post("tree.php", cloneTree);
```

When viewing firebug, this http request was successful but when viewing the file on the service file system, its empty...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to post, the html?

Comment: Are you sure your script is working? there is a syntax error in the posted code and why are you posting DOM Elements? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you cannot post a jquery object... you have to post an object `{post1:"whatever",post2:"whatever2"...}`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to post the html content of the clone copy...

Comment: Can I post html source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things

1) Remove the extra `"` around `#treeFile` and also `> *` from the end only if you want everything which is inside `ul`

```
 var cloneTree = $("#treeFile" > ul:first > li:first ul > *").clone(); //wrong
 var cloneTree = $("#treeFile > ul:first > li:first > ul").clone(); //correct
```

2) You can try this in order to post data via ajax

```
var cloneTree = $("#treeFile > ul:first > li:first > ul").html();
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/5QBYW/1/

Comment: i was preparing the fiddle .. i guess i am late in posting the answer :(

Answer (score 0):

If its the *HTML* you need to *POST*, you can do:

```
$.post("tree.php", {html: cloneTree.html()});
```

Data cannot be posted to a server without parameter names. In the above code, the name of your parameter is `html`.

On the server side, you can access this HTML as `$_POST['html']`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass html to the server as follows:

Note the syntax error in your code would result due to a misplaced quote:

```
var cloneTree = $("#treeFile > ul:first > li:first ul > *").clone();

$.post("tree.php", {html:cloneTree.html()});
```

Also, in case you were not aware, you do not need to clone the object to post its html.  You could just send it directly:

```
$.post("tree.php", {html:$("#treeFile > ul:first > li:first ul > *").html()});
```